# How to search customers based on multiple tags in Shopify?

Tags: api, rest, shopify

I want to search customers matching with tags Wholesale and VIP, how can I do this?

https://test.myshopify.com/admin/customers/search.json?query=Wholesale&VIP

Answer (score 2):

You can use %20 or space for and query :

https://test.myshopify.com/admin/customers/search.json?query=Wholesale%20VIP

https://test.myshopify.com/admin/customers/search.json?query=Wholesale VIP